# AOSP Repo stuck at 89%.

Tags: android-source

I am trying to download the Android repo and is stuck at 89%. I have tried all the options listed under "Known Issues" on source.android.com!

I Have tried

```
repo sync -f
```

completes the fetch but with errors.

Server is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
repo sync -j1
```

If your internet connection has less bandwidth. This would help you for spawning less no jobs. Actually one at a time.